# how to handle cookies

Tags: http-headers, session-cookies

I'm trying to program a script login to my electricity suppliers website to download some bills. Using a live headers plugin I see that there are about 4 different named cookies, and a new session cookie that is sent for each get/post, and about 6 redirects before the browser logs in.

But not all these cookies are sent back by the browser each time.

What determines which cookies need to be sent back for each get/post?

Edit: I am now wondering if the supplier might be using oauth from one part of their site to another for their authentication process as I see "oauth" in the GET parameters in their redirects so that might explain the number of redirects which was also puzzling me.

Answer (score 0):

> What determines which cookies need to be sent back for each get/post?

The [domain](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.3) and the [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.4) components of the cookie.

Comment: It's all against the same domain, but maybe it's the path that I was not looking at correctly.